# Increase Windows disk write-cache size

Tags: windows-10, ntfs

On my 32gb system, the maximum disk cache size used appears to be around 3.8gb, as observed in task manager as "Modified" memory, whilst under heavy write load.

This seems underpowered to me for my workload.

Is it possible to increase the windows write cache size limit?

I have tried `LargeSystemCache` and `Fsutil behavior set memoryusage 2` - these both had zero effect.

Edit: Purpose - I have an application that generates large amounts of data files. Ordinarily this would create a lot of random access writes (slow), but with plenty of cache, windows streamlines it into 130mb/s+ sequential writes. 3.8gb is enough for one application, but id like to run more

Comment: Windows workstation write cache size is normally not limiting.  Good article here:  https://superuser.com/questions/1272039/disk-write-cache-feature-and-limited-ram-usage-with-windows-10-pro-256gb-ddr4  .  Do you have a slow disk drive?

Comment: Why would you want to? On an HDD, it  might take 30 seconds or more to flush the write buffer to disk! Are you confusing this with the *pagefile*?

Comment: I have an application that generates large amounts of data files. Ordinarily this would create a lot of random access writes (slow), but with plenty of cache, windows streamlines it into 130mb/s+ sequential writes. 3.8gb is enough for one application, but id like to run more

Comment: Pretty sure this is one of those things where the answer is simply to use a real operating system such as linux

Comment: @DrMoishePippik How to do this opposite then? Windows says it's got 96GB cached, my external HDD maxes out at 100MB/s, that's a minimum of 16 **minutes** to flush the buffer.  I would *love* to force it to limit that to only 30 seconds...

Comment: I am struggling with the same. Trivial task in GNU/Linux, unfortunately not possible in Windows environment. Solution might be to run a virtual machine with GNU/Linux kernel to which you allocate a lot of RAM of your Windows host and run the IO expensive app there.